# Reinitializing Subscription Performance

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, replication

I have 4 Servers, Servers A, B, C, D.

Server A publishes a Replication instance, and Servers B, C, D have Pull Subscriptions to it.

Server B's subscription needs to be Reinitialized, but I am concerned that reinitializing it (Using the "current snapshot", not by generating a new one) will impact Replication Performance to the other Servers.

Should I be concerned, or because Servers B, C, and D have Pull (instead of Push) subscriptions, am I just over-thinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re-Initializing Subscriber using Current Snapshot or New Snapshot will not affect/impact other subscribers. Yes, you are overthinking it.**

Important thing you need to consider the amount of data (rows) that would have been added/updated/deleted since last time snapshot agent was generated and take the decision accordingly whether to Generate a New Snapshot or use existing one so that data is available back at the subscriber at the earliest.

For example: if last snapshot was generated 12 days ago and there were over 300,000 rows changed since last snapshot was generated. If you use current snapshot and delivery rate is say 2 rows per second it will take around 48 hours for data to completely synchronize to the subscriber that was re-initialized so this has nothing to do with other subscribers.

On other hand if you generate a new snapshot and reinitialize the new subscription database, it would be very quick and only time taken will be to create object/article scripts, replication objects and bulk copy the data.

Comment: But would generating a new snapshot impact the replication occurring on the other Servers?

Comment: No it will not impact.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how old the snapshot is.  After the snapshot is applied, the agent will need to also send all of the changes that have occurred since the snapshot was taken.  Depending on how many changes have occurred, this may or may not affect other existing subscribers.

I tend to take a new snapshot if possible before reinitializing a subscriber although sometimes that is not an option.

I wouldn't worry too much about it impacting other subscribers.